# How do I add a video to the Google search result from my website?

Tags: google-search

I own a website with some instructional videos. How do I make Google show snapshots of the videos in search results for website? (like it does for http://www.google.com/search?q=metallica+live&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official youtube.com or [msnbc.com](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&biw=1280&bih=850&q=ted&aq=f&aqi=g10&oq=&gs_rfai=))

When people search mywebsite.example.com, I want them to see snapshots of the videos I have and links to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't yet created a [Video Site Map](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/80471?hl=en), I'd start there:

> The Google video extension of the sitemap protocol enables you to give Google descriptive information—such as a video title, description, duration, etc.—that makes it easier for users to find a particular piece of content.

Comment: Cool, thank you very much, I will start with this.